# How to create a new variable with condition in R when data is long format?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to create a new conditional variable named `evHab` for my long format data.

This is the data I am working with:

```
canton      surfHab    year
Appenzell   377.2      1979-85
Appenzell   379.3      1992-97
Appenzell   422.0      2003-09
Appenzell   422.4      2013-18
Zürich      282.4      1979-85
Zürich      296.8      1992-97
Zürich      291.3      2003-09
Zürich      264.0      2013-18
Berne       383.4      1979-85
Berne       405.8      1992-97
Berne       432.7      2003-09
Berne       437.9      2013-18
Lucern      367.6      1979-85
Lucerne     377.6      1992-97
Lucerne     398.7      2003-09
Lucerne     385.2      2013-18
```

The new variable's condition is the difference between the `surfHab` in `1879-85` and in `2013-18` for each canton:

- If `surfHab in 2013-18 - surfHab in 1979-85 < 0, evHab = 1`
- If `surfHab in 2013-18 - surfHab in 1979-85 = 0, evHab = 2`
- If `surfHab in 2013-18 - surfHab in 1979-85 > 0, evHab = 3`

This what I have so far, using `group_by()` to have all distinctive *canton* and `mutate()` to create a new variable.

```
data_ofs %>% 
  group_by(canton) %>% 
    mutate(surfEv = ifelse((data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "2013-18"] - data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "1979-85"]) < 0, '1'), 
                    ifelse((data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "2013-18"] - data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "1979-85"]) == 0, '2'), 
                    ifelse((data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "2013-18"] - data_ofs$surfHab[data_ofs$year == "1979-85"]) > 0, '3')
                    )
```

The problem is that it gives me a lot of different errors :

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `surfEv`.
x Input `surfEv` can\'t be recycled to size 4.
ℹ Input `surfEv` is `ifelse(...)`.
ℹ Input `surfEv` must be size 4 or 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: canton = "Appenzell".
```

Is there a way to do this without having to pivot the table back to wide format ?

Comment: You mean `1979-85`?

Comment: @TarJae Yes! Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'canton', if we specify `data_ofs$`, it extracts the full column instead of the values within the group for each column and causing a length difference because the whole column is used for subsetting within in each group.  So, we can drop that `data_ofs$` in the code.  In addition, `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length i.e. subsetting `[` creates a change in length in one of the arguments

We could change the conditional statement (better with `case_when` instead of a nested `ifelse`).  In this particular case, none of them is required

```
library(dplyr)
data_ofs %>%
  group_by(canton) %>% 
  mutate(diff = surfHab[match('2013-18', year)] - 
                surfHab[match("1879-85", year)], 
         surfEv = match(sign(diff), c(-1, 0, 1)), diff = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation! This almost works be the new columns is all `NA`, any idea why?

Comment: @Melinda the reason is that your example doesn't have `1879-85` for year.  If it is `1979-85` please change it to that

Comment: @Melinda Please note that anything using `ifelse` on a subset data in the arguments is potential for bugs and is not correct

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of changing `1879`to `1979`:

```
data_ofs %>% 
  group_by(canton) %>% 
  mutate(surfEv = ifelse(surfHab[year == "2013-18"] - surfHab[year == "1979-85"] < 0, '1',
                         ifelse(surfHab[year == "2013-18"] - surfHab[year == "1979-85"] == 0, '2', '3')))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   canton [4]
   canton    surfHab year    surfEv
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
 1 Appenzell    377. 1979-85 3     
 2 Appenzell    379. 1992-97 3     
 3 Appenzell    422  2003-09 3     
 4 Appenzell    422. 2013-18 3     
 5 Zürich       282. 1979-85 1     
 6 Zürich       297. 1992-97 1     
 7 Zürich       291. 2003-09 1     
 8 Zürich       264  2013-18 1     
 9 Berne        383. 1979-85 3     
10 Berne        406. 1992-97 3     
11 Berne        433. 2003-09 3     
12 Berne        438. 2013-18 3     
13 Lucerne      368. 1979-85 3     
14 Lucerne      378. 1992-97 3     
15 Lucerne      399. 2003-09 3     
16 Lucerne      385. 2013-18 3
```

Data:

```
data_ofs <- data.frame(canton = c(rep("Appenzell",4), rep("Zürich",4), rep("Berne",4),rep("Lucerne",4)),
                       surfHab = c(377.2,379.2,422.0,422.4,282.4,296.8,291.3,264.0,383.4,405.8,432.7,437.9,367.6,377.6,398.7,385.2),
                       year = c("1979-85","1992-97","2003-09","2013-18","1979-85","1992-97","2003-09","2013-18","1979-85","1992-97","2003-09","2013-18","1979-85","1992-97","2003-09","2013-18"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I could make it work in my script! I went with @akrun answer as I find it easier without the ifelse().

Answer (score 1):

We could transform to wide and then do the calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- test
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = year,
    values_from = surfHab
  ) %>% 
  mutate(evHab = case_when(`2013-18` - `1979-85` < 0 ~ 1,
                           `2013-18` - `1979-85` == 0 ~ 2,  
                           `2013-18` - `1979-85` > 0 ~ 3))
```

Output:

```
  canton    `1979-85` `1992-97` `2003-09` `2013-18` evHab
  <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Appenzell      377.      379.      422       422.     3
2 Z??rich        282.      297.      291.      264      1
3 Berne          383.      406.      433.      438.     3
4 Lucern         368.       NA        NA        NA     NA
5 Lucerne         NA       378.      399.      385.    NA
```